# Changing all images in an array into something able to be classified

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I can load the images from a directory into an array, but how do I convert this array so that I can use it for classification?
By doing so I would also like to know how to reshape/resize all of the images in this array, and/if I could convert them from jpeg into something like a numpy array etc
What I have tried:

```
for filename in glob.glob('daisy/*.jpg'): 
    img=Image.open('daisy/')
    omg=misc.imresize(img, (32, 32))
    arr=array(img)
    training_set = Image.open(filename)
    lists.append(training_set)
```

Second version:

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("/daisy"):
    for filename in filenames:
        if re.search("\.(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|tiff)$", filename):
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            image = ndimage.imread(filepath, mode="RGB")
            image_resized = misc.imresize(image, (64, 64))
            images.append(image_resized)
            print(images)
```

3rd version

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread, imresize
import os

width, height = 50, 50

files = os.listdir("daisy")
images = [imread("daisy")+i for i in files]
resized = [imresize(i, (width, height)) for i in images]
images = np.array(resized)
```

Error messages that I can't get rid of:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'daisy'
```

This error message comes from the 2nd version

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'JpegImageFile'
```

I get this ^ error message when I added

```
pix=np.array(lists)
```

to the first version

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'data'
```

And finally I get this error message on the third version

Comment: What have you tried codewise? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I've tried glob, numpy, os, scipy. I get stuck when some errors are permission denied that I can't fix despite changing permissions. Some errors are also because I can't directly convert the picture array into a numpy array with np.array(lists) due to "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'JpegImageFile'"

Comment: Please edit your question rather than adding information in comments. Please also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Your question is still not specific and very likely will get downvotes or be deleted.

Comment: Edited to suit add the code